# Sync inbox between two accounts

Tags: python, exchangelib

I'm experimenting with the exchangelib.
What I'm trying to do is, sync the mails from the inbox folder, between to mailboxes.
I'm not sure if my way is the right one, but
my idea is to use sync_items() on the source account and then safe it to the target.

```
source_items = source_account.inbox.sync_items()
for change_type, item in source_items:
    print(change_type, item)
```

I can get all the mails I want with the code above. But I can't figure out, how to safe them to the target account. send_and_save() seems to send the mail again. I also tried export and upload, without success.

Is it even possible to do this? Any hints would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution depends on your needs. Some examples:

- Forward the messages to the other account:

```py
for m in this_account.inbox.all():
    m.forward(...)
```

- Save the messages to the other account:

```py
for m in this_account:
    m.account = other_account
    m.folder = other_account.inbox
    m.id = None
    m.changekey = None
    m.save()
```

- Export and upload messages:

```py
data = this_account.export(this_account.inbox.all())
other_account.upload(((other_account.inbox, d) for d in data))
```